# How can use the webRTC Javascript API to access the outgoing audio RTP timestamp at the sender and the incoming audio RTP timestamp at the receiver?

Tags: synchronization, webrtc

For instance, for the incoming audio stream at the receiver, this webRTC internal function gives me the RTP timestamp!

http://www.webrtc.org/reference/webrtc-internals/voevideosync#TOC-GetPlayoutTimeStamp

You could sniff all this information using WireShark. But I am looking to access this via a javascript function request?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the url you shared, that documentation is under "webrtc-internals" and describes how browsers should implement WebRTC inside the browser. Those low level functions are not available via Javascript.

You can find what's available (now or in the future) via Javascript [here](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html).